# Get "grub rescue" message when I try to reboot

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows

I am a complete novice so please don't give a highly technical answer.

I tried to install 14.04.1 LTS on my laptop. I used Windows 7 as OS. I tried to install the option `Ubuntu alongside Windows`. I did not install Ubuntu on my laptop's hard drive but on an external 1TB hard drive.

The installation completed successfully and message came that I must restart the machine to be able to use Ubuntu.

At first the machine did not turn off. It said something like

> "Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager' service name'.

It just froze on that black screen and I physically had to reboot again.

Then when it started up, it got to a screen which said:

> error:no such device: b788941c-14b1-41c8- . . Other numbers. . . .
>   Entering rescue mode . . .
>   Grub rescue  . . .

It seems that is waiting for an instruction

What should I do? I was hoping to be able to use any of the two systems Windows or Ubuntu depending on choice, but now I can't even log on to my old Windows system!!

Please help.

Comment: First of all is your external hard-drive connected to the system? and where was old windows os installed on external hard-drive or internal?

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is connected. The old OS was on the internal hd

Answer (score 1):

Try out this method

1. Boot up using a live CD.
2. Open a terminal using `Ctrl + Alt + T`
3. Type the following commands in order.

   ```
    sudo -s

    apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

    apt-get update

    apt-get install boot-repair

    exit

    boot-repair
   ```
4. When it asks to choose in which device you want to install grub, choose the internal hard drive(i.e. sda)

Comment: Thanks for trying. I got as far as your second line and it said that the PPA name is not correct. When I changed "yannububtu" to "yannubuntu" it gave an error saying "need a single repository as argument"?

Comment: Hi Ceda, can you please try to help me further? Tx

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong ppa. I have edited the command .... Please retry

Comment: Hi Ceda, I am still trying but can't get past the 2nd instruction.I type it in exactly as you say, but it then says "cannot add PPA:'ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the computer/laptop connected to Internet while you are doing so? It is necessary to connect to internet since the repository lies on an external server.

Comment: Thank you. No I don't think it is connected. I will try to connect later this morning when I go to the office. It is now 1h45 am here

Comment: If this answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as selected answer.

Comment: im using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and this worked for me. thanks @CedaEI

Answer (score 0):

[insert face palm here]
When you installed it to the external hard drive a bunch of other stuff (boot files) were on the external drive. So now your boot is messed up. In order to fix this you need some kind of windows recovery drive where you can boot to a console. Then refer to this helpful thread for help on fixing the MBR: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1335353
You can create a recovery drive from a windows PC on windows 10 (I'm not sure about other versions)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this if nothing else works?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that if you power on your machine USB external hard drive has not spined right away, BIOS did not recognized it and it is skipped on starting your computer.

On installation of Ubuntu you have rebooted computer and was not powered off. Same happened to external disc - it was not powered off.

In that case you can on first power on computer and error `error:no such device: b788941c-14b1-41c8- . . Other numbers. . . . Enetering rescue mode . . . Grub rescue . . .`, wait for few seconds and try to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete. When BIOS starts hold Shift key to get to GRUB menu.

In the GRUB menu you will probably have option to select Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7.

To repair windows 7 boot it is best option to repair Windows 7 boot with Windows 7 DVD

1. Power off computer
2. Unplug external hard disk
3. Insert Windows 7 DVD
4. Boot from Windows 7 DVD
5. Follow [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) instructions to repair boot from Windows 7 DVD

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I did as you suggested and got to a menu after pressing esc. BIOS setup is F10 on that menu. Is that where I had to be? Pressing the shift key has no effect there

Comment: No, I think this is BIOS menu. You need to get somehow to GRUB menu (screen has usually purple background) with booting options for installed operating system which is accessed with SHIFT key. If you have Windows 7 DVD at your disposal I would suggest you to repair Windows 7 boot with Windows 7 DVD.